# How to Form-encode a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, http, http-post

I am interacting with a REST API and need to explicitly form-encode the request body before sending.

The urllib module has a `urlencode` method, but I see no equivalent for form-encode, presumably as dictionaries are automatically encoded when using urllib to POST the request.

Is there a built in method that I can use to form-encode an object? For example:

```
params={'f':'json','type':'map'}
post_body = formencode(params)
```

Producing post_body:

```
f=json
type=map
```

In this instance I'm using [WinHttpRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) through the win32com module as it can take care of authentication natively so I don't need to handle credentials in the script.

Comment: I believe this functionality should be a part of http library you're using.

Comment: Thanks @DarthKotik, unfortunately winhttprequest is pretty low level and doesn't handle encoding. I'm hoping there's something available elsewhere in a built-in python module that can help me..

Answer (score 0):

> The normal call to urllib.parse.urlencode should give you a string
> that's correct for sending as x-www-form-urlencoded data.

See [this related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72702942/2754436) for more info on the `urlencode` method inside urllib.parse.