# Converting dictionary to url encoded data for passing application/x-www-form-urlencoded in python

Tags: python, dictionary, parameters, path

I have a dictionary like this

```py
data = {
   "name":"test name",
   "file_urls":[
      "/Users/tarequzzamankhan/Desktop/instagram.webp",
      "/Users/tarequzzamankhan/Desktop/instagram.webp"
   ],
   "file_type":"pdf",
   "user_name":"Tareq",
   "mobile":"018xxxxxxxxx",
   "address":"Dhaka",
   "email":"example@mail.com"
}
```

I want to convert this dict to a query string like:

```
payload='name=test%20name&file_urls=%5B%22%2FUsers%2Ftarequzzamankhan%2FDesktop%2Finstagram.webp%22%2C%20%22%2FUsers%2Ftarequzzamankhan%2FDesktop%2Finstagram.webp%22%5D&file_type=pdf&user_name=Tareq&mobile=018xxxxxxxxx&address=Dhaka&email=example%40mail.com'
```

For calling an api

I used 
`urllib.parse.urlencode(data, doseq=True)` 
 
 but it can not generate the same string provided above, instead it generates:

```
payload='name=test+name&file_urls=%2FUsers%2Ftarequzzamankhan%2FDesktop%2Finstagram.webp&file_urls=%2FUsers%2Ftarequzzamankhan%2FDesktop%2Finstagram.webp&file_type=pdf&user_name=Tareq&mobile=018xxxxxxxxx&address=Dhaka&email=example%40mail.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

The normal call to `urllib.parse.urlencode` should give you a string that's correct for sending as `x-www-form-urlencoded` data. However, to answer your question about the resulting string formatting...

[`urllib.parse.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) has a keyword argument called `quote_via`, which allows you to specify a method for how some characters like spaces or slashes are encoded, and by default they are done with `urllib.parse.quote_plus` where spaces are substituted with `+`. You can use `urllib.parse.quote` instead, which will get you a string like what you want.

> The resulting string is a series of key=value pairs separated by '&'
> characters, where both key and value are quoted using the quote_via
> function. By default, quote_plus() is used to quote the values, which
> means spaces are quoted as a '+' character and ‘/’ characters are
> encoded as %2F, which follows the standard for GET requests
> (application/x-www-form-urlencoded). An alternate function that can be
> passed as quote_via is quote(), which will encode spaces as %20 and
> not encode ‘/’ characters. For maximum control of what is quoted, use
> quote and specify a value for safe.

```
import urllib.parse

data = {
   "name":"test name",
   "file_urls":[
      "/Users/tarequzzamankhan/Desktop/instagram.webp",
      "/Users/tarequzzamankhan/Desktop/instagram.webp"
   ],
   "file_type":"pdf",
   "user_name":"Tareq",
   "mobile":"018xxxxxxxxx",
   "address":"Dhaka",
   "email":"example@mail.com"
}

# I didn't use doseq=True because you seem to want all the `file_urls` as a single argument
qs = urllib.parse.urlencode(data, quote_via=urllib.parse.quote)

print(qs)
```

Output:

```
In [24]: print(qs)
name=test%20name&file_urls=%5B%27%2FUsers%2Ftarequzzamankhan%2FDesktop%2Finstagram.webp%27%2C%20%27%2FUsers%2Ftarequzzamankhan%2FDesktop%2Finstagram.webp%27%5D&file_type=pdf&user_name=Tareq&mobile=018xxxxxxxxx&address=Dhaka&email=example%40mail.com
```

Comment: Still there is some problem Like `"` replaced by `%27` but I need `%22`

Comment: @TarequzzamanKhan If that is a hard requirement, then the simplest thing to do here is to add the line `qs.replace("%27", "%22")` after the `urlencode` line. Then the query string should be equal to the `payload` you specified.

Comment: @ 逆さま finally I got a solution and it works for me perfectly. I will add the answer later